# All is executed, although the list is empty

Tags: c#, linq

```
namespace ConsoleApplication15
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;

  public class Test
  {
    public string Status { get; set; }
  }

  public static class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var list = new List<Test>();

      if (list.Any(x => x.Status == "Tester"))
      {
        Console.WriteLine("This Line will not execute");
      }

      if (list.All(x => x.Status == "Tester"))
      {
        Console.WriteLine("This line will execute");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain to my please why the line All condiation is executed and the Any not?
All--> The list does not contains items!

Comment: well, were there any list items where the status wasn't `"Tester"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enumerable.All` would return true if the the source sequence *(in your case a list)* is empty.

This is documented for [Enumerable.All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)

> **Return Value:** true if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the
>   specified predicate, **or if the sequence is empty**; otherwise,
>   false.

Comment: Thanks Habib, it is for me not reasonable but it seem to be it working like that.

Comment: @BassamAlugili, that is the documented behaviour, and it may look weird, but that is how it works.

Comment: @BassamAlugili, See :),  [vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) A vacuous truth is a statement that asserts that all members of the empty set have a certain property. For example, the statement "all cell phones in the room are turned off" may be true simply because there are no cell phones in the room. In this case, the statement "all cell phones in the room are turned on" would also be true, and vacuously so, as would the conjunction of the two: "all cell phones in the room are turned on and turned off".

Answer (score 4):

> true if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the specified predicate, or if the sequence is empty; otherwise, false.

Base on the MSDN statement, you got the result is **True** . [Enumerable.All() Method MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the implementation of `All` method:

```
public static bool All<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (TSource element in source) 
    {
       if (!predicate(element)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can see that it tries to iterate over the elements.But since there is no element in the source sequence, it's immediately return **true**.On the other hand the `Any` method:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) 
{
    foreach (TSource element in source) 
    {
       if (predicate(element)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Does the same thing but it immediately return `false`.

Answer (score 3):

`.All()` executes because it's literally true that every item in the list meets the condition. There are zero items in the list, and zero items meet the condition. That's **all** of them.

`.Any()` doesn't execute because the number of matching items is zero. Any has to be more than zero.

Think of it this way: *Every time* I eat a giraffe, `All` the time, I get indigestion. But I have never actually eaten a giraffe. It has not happened `Any` times.